# What does this map mean?

Tags: warframe

While messing around in the Plains of Eidolon, me and my squad came across this:

[image]

Activating the console caused some machinery around the room to rumble for a few moments and made one of the 3 little white balls on the map blink (a different one each time).

Outside this hut, there is a grid system of poles and wires connecting them, so we were able to determine that the white balls seemed to correlate to large piles of dirt where the Grineer appear to have been digging.  These dirt piles also had a strange red look to them when viewed from the air.

However, we were unable to find any difference between the dirt pile whose white ball had blinked and the ones who hadn't.  We even tried looking around with the synthesis scanner in case there was a hidden entity it could reveal, but found nothing.

Is that it?  Is there something in the dirt?  What does the map mean?  What does activating this console ultimately lead to?

Comment: I can't confirm this, but I've heard hitting those consoles makes one of the dirt piles explode and makes Grokdrul appear where it was.

Comment: @Powerlord I find it unlikely that we wouldn't have noticed this, and it's also a strange place to put grokdrul considering how common and easy-to-acquire grokdrul is.  Though it could be possible, I suppose...

Comment: Every time I go to that spot, I am careful not to shoot the red things that hang from the ceiling because they explode, and use the console. There are ~4 pumps inside that room that will start to move. After 1 or some pulses it gives energy. I never noticed the change on the map though.

Answer (score 4):

From the Warframe wiki:

> Inside the circular command tent, a holographic map of the immediate
>   area can be found. Activating the switch next to the map will
>   highlight one of three possible locations with a glowing dot on the
>   map, and will deploy an automated mining explosive (similar to a Dreg)
>   from the tent to that location. When it reaches its target, the
>   explosive drone will detonate, revealing fossilized Sentient wreckage
>   and some random assorted resources or Credits.

More information can be found [here](https://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Plains_of_Eidolon#Grineer_Excavation).